# How to place a table or image dynamically to pdf in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, tcpdf, mpdf

I've a pdf file of a rule that need to pass a several approval. In the end of the file (content), I need to:

1. Add a QR Code as an e-sign in the specific place, or
2. Add a border-less table that include some text and a QR Code after the last content of the pdf. Which mean if the last content of pdf ends in the height(x) of 200, then the content should placed in (as an example) the height(x) of 210.

[image: Example]

Is that possible?

TCPDF `writeHtml` will place the generated html in the top of the page, while `writeHTMLCell` and `MultiCell` will need a specific `x` and `y` to be defined.

I'm also trying in MPDF, but it stuck like the TCPDF.

The code before writing the html looks like this,

```php
$pageCount = PDF::setSourceFile($file);
$template = PDF::importPage($i);
$size = PDF::getTemplateSize($template);
PDF::AddPage($size['orientation'], array($size['width'], $size['height']));
PDF::useTemplate($template);

// After this, I need to call writeHtml, writeHTMLCell, or MultiCell, but none of those met what I need.
// Or placing an image with PDF::Image also need to define the x and y
...
// PDF::SetX()
// PDF::SetY()
// PDF::Image($qrPath, null, null, 12, 12, 'PNG');
// PDF::WriteHTML(view('document-requests.approver.stamp', ['qr' => $qrPath]), true, false, true, false, '');
PDF::Output($file, 'F');
```

#Edit

Another thing from `mPDF` is that there's an [`Overwrite`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/overwrite.html) method, but it's only overwrite the content created/generated by the library itself.

Comment: just to be more clear.. are you saying that the dynamic content resulting from `useTemplate` will have a different height each time? and by the way, does it always remain in one single page? if the answer is yes, can't you just render your box at a fixed y being the most bottom area of the page?

Comment: plus I see you are using static methods.. and you have no instance of your document. Shouldn't you have something like `$pdf = new TCPDF();`? and call its methods? so that you may also rely on `$pdf->GetY()` and `$pdf->WriteHTMLCell()`

Comment: Are you trying to say is that the content length of the PDF file can vary, and therefore the position where the additions need to be made? In that case you need some way to detect the bottom of the content in the file. Right?

Comment: @DiegoD Yes, the last content depends on user, it's something like a letter document that need a sign in the end. And no, I can't put it in the most bottom area of the page, because if the last content of my pdf only 3 or 4 lines, it would be weird with the most of the middle page was blank. About the instantiating the TCPDF Class, I use the [Laravel Package](https://github.com/elibyy/tcpdf-laravel) and that's how to use it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Right, and I can't find any way to detect the last content of a pdf.

Comment: @KJ Hmm...you're right, any content of a pdf looks like an object and could be moved away. But, I think I still need to construct it like what I've explained, since it's related to a non-tech people that only need the document to be constructed like that.

Comment: @KJ Well, actually it would be good if all pdf contents is a generated content. But that's another problem to work with Docx dynamically (they've their own template for this). Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: ....ya, pdf content is an editable object, could be easily (re)moved with any pdf reader that supports editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stuck for looking an automated way, I use a Client Side approach, and written the full way [here](https://thearkas.medium.com/how-to-place-an-image-into-pdf-files-with-dynamic-positions-in-laravel-with-javascript-a1898fde1060). But for a glance, the steps are:

1. User load PDF using [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) (from Mozilla), place it in a canvas,
2. Use [interact.js](https://interactjs.io) for making a div draggable, and assume that draggable-div as a QR to be placed,
3. Could some calculation, since html canvas return a *px* while TCPDF return in *cm*.

The results so far have been good

Comment: @KJ I guess you put the QR-div too far at the bottom, because there is some kind of margin in the pdf so it moves to the next page (just need to re-arrange the config of setasign I thought). And you're right about the PDF Reader, but that is a PDF Reader. I mean User/Client needs it in Web App, and sometimes they doesn't met that price for integrating Desktop PDF Reader within a Web App Framework (Laravel in this case).

Answer (score -1):

**Answer:**

It is possible to add a QR code to a specific location in a PDF using TCPDF or MPDF, but it will require some additional work, as none of the built-in functions directly meet your needs.

1. **TCPDF:**

To add a QR code to a specific location in a PDF using TCPDF, you can use this code :

```
<?php

require_once('tcpdf.php');

// Create a new PDF document.
$pdf = new TCPDF();

// Add a new page to the PDF document.
$pdf->AddPage();

// Set the font for the QR code.
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

// Generate the QR code.
$qrCode = $pdf->write2DBarcode('http://www.example.com', 'QRCODE,H', 10, 10, 30, 30, '', '');

// Position the QR code at the desired location on the page.
$pdf->SetX(100);
$pdf->SetY(100);

// Output the PDF document.
$pdf->Output('example.pdf');

?>
```

2. **MPDF:**

To add a QR code to a specific location in a PDF using MPDF, you can use Code :

```
<?php

require_once('mpdf/mpdf.php');

// Create a new PDF document.
$mpdf = new mPDF();

// Set the drawing font for the QR code.
$mpdf->SetDrawingFont('helvetica', '', 10);

// Generate the QR code.
$qrCode = $mpdf->Image($qrPath, null, null, 12, 12, 'PNG');

// Position the QR code at the desired location on the page.
$mpdf->SetXY(100, 100);

// Output the PDF document.
$mpdf->Output('example.pdf');

?>
```

- If you need to add QR Code in your PDF then you need to add this code where you need to put.

```
$pdf->WriteHTML('<table><tr><td><img src="qr_code.png" /></td><td>Some text</td></tr></table>');
```

- To position the table at the end of the PDF, you can use the SetY() function to set the Y position to the height of the PDF document. You can get the height of the PDF document using the GetPageHeight() function. You can use the below code when you are using TCPDF to position the table:

```
$pdf->SetY($pdf->GetPageHeight());
```

Once you have positioned the table at the end of the PDF, you can output the PDF document.

I hope this helps to you.

Comment: I'm curious if I was missing some specific description about my problem. But as per my code example, the QR Code would be placed with an already generated image and placed with `Image()` function. So placing QR Code to a specific location is not the main problem, instead the content was dynamic which mean that the `SetX` and `SetY` need to be defined dynamically. Also, `GetPageHeight()` will return the height of the page just like `$sizes` from `getTemplateSize`, that mean every content written after that will placed in the next page.

Comment: May be i understand your concern now. I think challenge is that neither TCPDF nor MPDF provides a built-in way to dynamically set the X and Y coordinates of an image or table. So i think you will need to calculate the X and Y coordinates yourself. First get the height of the last content on the page using the GetY() function. Second add the desired height of the QR code or table to the height of the last content to get the new Y coordinate. and then set the X coordinate to the desired location on the page.

Comment: Unfortunately, GetY() and GetX() is not returning the last content of imported PDF.

Comment: Sorry for late replay, I think TCPDF does not track the positions of the individual elements, so there is no built-in way to get the position of the last content on an imported page. So i think you need to use workaround.

Comment: Can you do like this :-  add the imported page to the current page using the AddTemplate() function and then get the height of the current page using the GetPageHeight() function. Subtract the height of the imported page from the height of the current page to get the height of the last content on the imported page. Use the SetY() function to set the Y coordinate to the height of the last content on the imported page. Place your QR code or table at the desired location on the page using the Image() or WriteHTML() function, respectively.
I think this is help you.

Comment: The imported page's height and width is as the same as current page after `AddTemplate()`. So yeah, TCPDF could not detect any object/content from imported pdf, or the imported page have that long of content (even there's only 1 or 2 lines in that page).

Comment: I think you are correct. I have do research on TCPDF and found that TCPDF treats an imported PDF page as a single image, and does not track the positions of the individual elements on the page. This means that the GetPageHeight() function will return the same height for both the imported page and the current page after AddTemplate() is called. I have tried everything to the best of my knowledge but I still haven't found a solution to your problem, which I will regret. If you get the answer to this in future, please let me know so that I can further increase my knowledge. Sorry.